# How to convert number(16,10) to date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to read the Borland Starteam application oracle database
and I noticed that they represent their date as a number(16,10) column.
I think it is not timestamp or epoch.  For instance, I have the number: 37137.4347569444, how can I read it as date?

I saw that the database has a stored procedure, CONVERT_DATE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure STARBASE.convert_date 
      ( number_of_days IN integer 
         , nDate OUT number) 
is 
    nDateOffset number; 
    CurrentDate date; 
    Month integer; 
    Day integer; 
    year number; 
    success boolean := false; 
    bLeapYear boolean:=false;
    nDaysInMonths number; 
    nLeapDays integer; 
    fDate number (16,10); 
    rgMonthDays number(5,0); 
begin 
    select sysdate - number_of_days 
    into CurrentDate 
    from dual; 
    nDateOffset := 693959; 
    select to_number(substr((TO_CHAR (CurrentDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) , 1, 2), '99') - 1 
    into month 
    from dual; 
    select to_number(substr((TO_CHAR (CurrentDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) , 4, 2), '99') - 1 
    into day 
    from dual; 
    select to_number(substr((TO_CHAR (CurrentDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) , 7, 4), '9999') 
    into year 
    from dual; 
    if ( mod(year , 4) = 0 ) 
        and ( ( mod(year , 400) = 0) or ( mod(year , 100) <> 0 )) 
    then
        bLeapYear :=true; 
    end if; 
    nLeapDays := 0; 
    if ( bLeapYear = true) and ( Day = 28) and ( Month = 1 ) 
    then 
        nLeapDays := 1; 
    end if; 
    select substr(to_char(last_day(CurrentDate) , 'DD-MM-YYYY') , 1 , 2)
    into nDaysInMonths 
    from dual; 
    if Month = 0 then 
        rgMonthDays := 0; 
    elsif Month = 1 then 
         rgMonthDays := 31; 
    elsif Month = 2 then 
        rgMonthDays := 59; 
    elsif Month = 3 then 
        rgMonthDays := 90; 
    elsif Month = 4 then 
        rgMonthDays := 120; 
     elsif Month = 5 then 
         rgMonthDays := 151; 
     elsif Month = 6 then 
         rgMonthDays := 181; 
     elsif Month = 7 then 
         rgMonthDays := 212; 
     elsif Month = 8 then
         rgMonthDays := 243; 
     elsif Month = 9 then
         rgMonthDays := 273; 
     elsif Month = 10 then 
         rgMonthDays := 304; 
     elsif Month = 11 then 
         rgMonthDays := 334; 
     elsif Month = 12 then 
         rgMonthDays := 365; 
     end if;
     nDate := Year*365 + Year/4 - Year/100 + Year/400 + rgMonthDays + Day + 1; 
     if( Month < 2 ) and ( bLeapYear = true) then 
         nDate := nDate - 1;
     end if;
     nDate := nDate - nDateOffset; 
 exception 
     when others then raise; 
end convert_date;
```

I don't know how to use it.

how can i read it anyway?
Please help.
thank you

Comment: That depends on how the date is encoded in the number. Show us several rows of sample data and perhaps we can help.

Comment: @Elad: Can you find out what date `37137.4347569444` is supposed to be?

Comment: Ok, I saw in the database an store procedure that maybe could help.
I'll update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 693959 is the clue here. That is the number of days from 1/1/00 (the year zero never existed, but I digress) to 12/30/1899. That date was often used as the epoch for older databases where date was represented as a double. So something like this should put you back in business:

```
CREATE FUNCTION float_to_date(p_days NUMBER)
RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date('1899-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + p_days;
END;
```

Test it of course. The number 37137.4347569444 should correspond to 2001-09-03 10:26:03.

Comment: Strange to go from Dec 30th rather than 31st.
When dealing with anything that counts from the year zero (or one), bear in mind that officially there were ten days dropped in 1582 because of the switch from Julian to Gregorian.

Comment: Thanks!
unfortunately I can't give you points because my low reputation, but awesome! It helps!